# batch file - wmic - empty line

Tags: batch-file, findstr, wmic

looking over google I am trying to create a batch file with output the list of disks and free space. I found a good solution but for each drive listed there is an 1 space empty line (the line start with a **space** " " and so CR LF for new line).
What do you suggest ?

```
 @ECHO OFF
set FILE="testOK.txt"
set IP="127.0.0.1"
set PC="EA"
set TAB="   "
SETLOCAL enableextensions
(for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('
  WMIC LOGICALDISK GET FreeSpace^,Name^,Size ^|FINDSTR /I /V "Name"
  ') do (       
        echo wsh.echo date ^& %TAB% ^& time ^& %TAB% ^& %ip% ^& %TAB% ^& %PC% ^& %TAB% ^& "%%b" ^& %TAB% ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%%a^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^) ^& "  " ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%%c^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^)^& "  GB" > "%temp%\tmp.vbs"
        
        if not "%%b"=="" (
          echo( 
          cscript //nologo "%temp%\tmp.vbs"
          del "%temp%\tmp.vbs"
    )
    
  )
) > %FILE%
```

Example result:

```
01/07/2020  10:20:59    10.0.13.36  ADMINPC C:  4,07    69,90   GB
 
01/07/2020  10:20:59    10.0.13.36  ADMINPC E:  0,00    0,42    GB
```

Comment: `echo(` writes an empty line...

Comment: also it's inefficient to create the `vbs` file several times. Create it once (before the loop) and delete it once (after the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep this answer on topic, here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which uses [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) and [wmi](/questions/tagged/wmi), *(not [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic))*, to achieve your goal, and without creating an intermediate `.vbs` or all of those variables:

```batch-file
<!-- :
@"%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf">"testOK.txt"
@Exit /B
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
Set c=CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set i=GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
Set o=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each n In i:If n.IPEnabled Then IP=n.IPAddress(0):End If:Next
For Each Drv In o.Drives:If Drv.IsReady=True Then
  WScript.Echo Date&VBTab&Time&VBTab&IP&VBTab&c.ComputerName&VBTab&_
  Drv.DriveLetter&":"&VBTab&Round(Drv.FreeSpace/1073741824,2)&VBTab&_
  Round(Drv.TotalSize/1073741824,2)&" GiB"
End If:Next
</Script></Job>
```

Comment: it is work very good ! One last question is, how to append at the end of the file instead of overwrite it ?

Comment: Change `>"testOK.txt"` to `>>"testOK.txt"`, @FabioDiBartolomei.

Comment: consider than I am trying to do that for all the PCs in the network, the idea is to point at the same file in a shared folder. There is a easy way to check that writing has been done or retry ? (for instance is possible that 2 pc are writing in the file in the same time, so one of them would failed)

Comment: Your methodology is wrong @FabioDiBartolomei, if that's what you're doing. But it would not be appropriate to coach you in the methodology after you've asked and I've answered your question, especially as my answer would unlikely be part of it.